# Raspberry Pi 2 As Inbetween From GPIO Device To PC

Tags: gpio, usb, pi-2

So I'm not sure if this specifically has been asked before, as I had a look around, and most of the questions relating to USB stuff seemed to be about using the Pi as a USB flash drive.

I was wondering if it was possible to use the Raspberry Pi as an inbetween of sorts to send control from a controller that I have hooked up to the GPIO pins of the board to a computer. Hence using the Pi as a sort of USB Controller board for the PC.

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Update:

To clarify my question a little, I currently have a Raspberry Pi 2, and have built a very basic arcade control setup. This is hooked up the the GPIO of the Pi, and is used as input for games etc.

I also have a PC which I would quite like to use these arcade controls on, but no way to directly plug them into the PC without a USB board for the controls themselves.

To reiterate above, I was looking for a way to use these arcade controls through the RPi, and somehow connect the RPi to my computer, and use the controls hooked up to the RPi with my computer.

If it matters, the arcade controls are using key presses from a keyboard as inputs, would there be a way to send these to a computer at all?

Comment: You don't need raspberry for such things, just use STM32. Even small STM32 will give you much more usefull GPIOs whether raspberry.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  I'm not sure why you mention USB.  It may be better to use an Arduino.  You haven't given enough detail to properly answer your question.

Comment: I've added a little more information to try and help clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

This would be relatively straightforward with the Raspberry Pi Zero.  Since it has a USB OTG port, it could be used as a USB device. [Hackaday](http://hackaday.com/2015/12/27/turning-the-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/) has some links to interesting tutorials on how such things can be accomplished.

Comment: I appreciate the information but I was looking for an answer more relating to the RPi2. I've updated the question with some more information to show this a little more clearly now.

Comment: @zamorikan: I think the easiest way to make such a connection would be to have a serial to usb setup and have your PC wait for information over that bus.  It's not as straight forward, but it is doable, and would have significantly less latency than a network connection.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Would you have any references for where to start with something like that? Haven't had a lot of luck finding anything immediately useful online.